# Would this question be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Almost all of the questions here are about how we, the makers of things, can make them with the best user experience.  That makes sense, of course.  Are questions from the user side rather than the builder side also on-topic (so long as they are not "how do I do X in product Y" questions)?

The specific question I want to ask is: *As a user, how can I find a consultant to help me improve the accessibility of my workspace?*  I am having some vision-accessibility difficulties at work and no one here can do anything better than guess about ways to improve things.  I'd like to find a consultant that we can bring in to advise on specific changes/accommodations, but none of us know how to *find* that consultant.

We have plenty of [accessibility](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accessibility) questions about compliance from the perspective of the company or programmer making the product, but those answers aren't helping me from the user side.

Would such a question be on-topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UX is a site for user experience researchers and designers, not for users.

I think if you're looking for help improving your workspace, you should look for a Stack that deals with that topic specifically. [DIY Stack Exchange](https://diy.stackexchange.com/) may be able to help. [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) has several questions about workspaces (for programmers) as well, and that site by its very nature is slightly more meta than most.

Alternatively you can try rewording the question so it's posed from a designer's point of view, eg. "How can I improve this workspace for people with limited vision?" - you'd need to explain in more detail what's going on, but that question might pass the FAQ test.